# No data displaying with this ajax request on a php page

Tags: javascript, ajax

## Summary

I am trying to display data on a PHP page using ajax to send a request to a separate PHP page which connects and pulls data from a mysql database. The end results should be a user clicks a button, and without the need to refresh, data from a database is displayed on the same page.

## Files

**displaydata.php**

- This is the page the client sees, and displays the data.

**getData.php**

- This is what connects to the MySQL database and pulls the data.

**app.js**

- This is where the ajax request is made.

## My Problem

Currently, when I run the code I have, I click the button I want to call the ajax request, and the page refreshes displaying no data.

I have run it and used the Inspect Element, and found that the requests are being sent successfully with a status 200, which I know to be OK. At the top of the app.js document, I set a console.log("app.js found") to test if the document was being read at all. This displays in the console of the Inspect Element, but other console.log()'s I have put within the function do not display.

## Code

#### app.js

```
function init() {
  document.getElementById("Submit").addEventListener('click', ajax);
}

function ajax() {
  console.log("Function started");
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'getData.php', true);
  request.onload = function() {
    console.log(request);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
      // Success!
      document.getElementById("displayData").innerHTML = request.responseText;
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  };
  request.send();
  console.log("Request sent");
}
document.addEventListener('load', init);
```

#### displaydata.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <p class='title'>Presenting udp packet data</p><hr />
   <center><div class='data-window'>
   <form id="getSearchNumber">
     <label for="imei">IMEI of desired devices</label> 
     <select name="imei" id="imei">
       <option value="Alldata">All Data</option>
       <option value="012981000298213">012981000298213</option>
     </select>
     <br />
     <button id="Submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
   <div id="displayData"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I know the getData.php code is working correctly, but if anybody wants to see it, leave a comment.

I don't think it's a syntax error, but rather an error in approach to the problem.

Comment: Any reason for not using jQuery at this?

Comment: Originally I decided not to, as a way of truly understanding what was going on in the process. I now realise that may have been a mistake at my level, and have started trying with jQuery, still no luck though. I will accept answers in either form.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery in your page and change the `<button>` to `<input type="button"` just because will submit the form if you use it.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body>
       <p class='title'>Presenting udp packet data</p><hr />
       <center><div class='data-window'>
       <form id="getSearchNumber">
         <label for="imei">IMEI of desired devices</label> 
         <select name="imei" id="imei">
           <option value="Alldata">All Data</option>
           <option value="012981000298213">012981000298213</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
       </form>
       <div id="displayData"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The change your JS to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
        $( "#displayData" ).load( "getData.php" );
    });
})
```